# Is it possible to trigger a Github workflow only once for a pull request?

Tags: triggers, github-actions

With a workflow file like this:

```
on: [push, pull_request]
```

runs are triggered for each single commit in a pull request.

Is it possible to only trigger once, for the pull request (including all commits) as a whole?

I just got literally hundreds of runs for a bigger pull request...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Webhook events](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events) page:

> By default, all activity types trigger a workflow to run. You can
> limit your workflow runs to specific activity types using the `types`
> keyword. For more information, see "[Workflow syntax for GitHub
> Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onevent_nametypes)."

---

The [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) event has many activities associated with it that trigger any actions that listen for that event. Activities such as **`synchronize`** or **`edited`** might contribute to the reasons why your action is being called whenever the pull request is modified.

You can limit the activity types using the `types` list. For example:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
```

In the above case, the action will only run **when a pull request is *opened***. You can add more to this list as you see fit.

Comment: You were right. It happened only for automatic pull requests from crowdin.com/ - they seem to edit already opened pull requests constantly.

Answer (score 2):

### you can use this as first job and remaining jobs will not be executed

```
jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check if workflow has already run
        id: check_workflow_status
        uses: actions/github-script@v4
        with:
          script: |
            const response = await github.repos.listWorkflowRuns({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              event: 'push',
              branch: 'main',
              per_page: 1,
              status: 'completed'
            });

            const completedWorkflows = response.data.workflow_runs.filter(run => run.conclusion === 'success');
            const hasCompletedWorkflow = completedWorkflows.length > 0;

            console.log(`Has completed workflow? ${hasCompletedWorkflow}`);

            if (hasCompletedWorkflow) {
              core.setFailed('Workflow has already been run.');
            } else {
              console.log('Workflow can continue.');
            }
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Hi, I just put your code into a code block.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.